# ASP.NET Common Preparation Functions and Their Results

Tags: asp.net, function, scope

Let's say I want to run the same function on every one of my .aspx pages.  Let's say this function always results in a UTC DateTime and the user's DateTime, for example.  How can I write code in one place that will both compute these values for every page load and then make their values available to the entire .aspx page?
I realize I could declare these variables in each page and then call the function, but isn't there a way to write it once to avoid writing the same code repeatedly?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a master page. Even if you do not have anything visible from the master page, you could have its onload or oninit do the calculation, the store it as a property of the master page.

```
public Date date{get;set;}
protected void onLoad(){ 
    this.date = ... calculate ....; 
}
```

then from the child page you can access the master page

```
((YourMasterClassName)this.Master).date
```

Comment: Even though I didn't use your solution for my case, I think it's a good one.  Thank you!